# How to prove $\dfrac{\cosh(\pi)}{1^7}+\dfrac{\cosh(2\pi)}{2^7}+\dfrac{\cosh(3\pi)}{3^{7}}+...=\dfrac{19\pi^{7}}{56700}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Here is an identity from Ramanjan's letter. It captivates me. How do you prove this?

$\dfrac{\cosh(\pi)}{1^7}+\dfrac{\cosh(2\pi)}{2^7}+\dfrac{\cosh(3\pi)}{3^{7}}+...=\dfrac{19\pi^{7}}{56700}$

Comment: Well, it is a divergent series. Meaning that the expression is discussing an analytic continuation, the same way people ask about Euler's divergent series that were simply giving values of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: @will jagy how can we test if this series is divergent?

Comment: a term is basically $\frac{e^{n \pi}}{2 n^7}$

Comment: I don't understand how did you derive it?

Comment: $$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2},$$ so each term is $$t_n=\frac{e^{n\pi}+e^{-n\pi}}{2n^7}.$$ The $e^{-n\pi}$ bit is negligible for large $n$, so $$\frac{e^{n\pi}}{2n^7}<t_n< \frac{e^{n\pi}}{2n^7}+1,$$ and since $\frac{e^{n\pi}}{2n^7}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, $\sum_{n}t_n$ diverges.

Comment: @Will Jagy: So the result is wrong, or it is summed using a different summation method for divergent series?